# Angular: --prod vs -prod

Tags: angular

In angular 2 I believe you have to use:

```
enableProductionMode()
```

Which I call in my environment.prod.ts file.

Then I can call:

```
ng b -prod
```

But in angular 5+ I can do the following:

```
ng b -- --prod --aot
```

And I do not need an environment.prod.ts file

What are the differences between the two ways to run prod and are they the same?

Comment: A little off topic, but related to the title only. When you are provided with the option of having single dash (like *** -version) and two dashes (*** --version) - there is a difference where the output is received. For example with Java - one writes to `System.out` and the other to `System.err`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure you got it right.

In all versions of angular, the `prod` flag is simply a shorthand for production mode : it enables AOT (in previous versions, now it's by default, `--aot`), filename hashing, minification, uglyfication  (`--optimization` for all 3), ...

... and it uses a particular environment file. Most of the times the file was called `environment.prod.ts`, but that's a coincidence : the file to be used is declared in the `angular.json` file.

If you don't need a `.prod.ts` environment file, it probably means that your configurations for the `production` target use another file, which isn't `.prod.ts`. But that's because of your project, not because of the command line.

and `enableProdMode()` (that you will find in `main.ts`) is called **only** when your environment file contains the `production` flag to true : it doesn't decide if you are in production mode, the environment file does.

Finally, about the command lines : in the latest versions of Angular, they switched to [POSIX notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html), which forces people to use the double hyphen  `--` for words, and single hypen for letters (or combination of letters).

The `-- --prod` (double hyphens without any flags) notation means that you send flags following those hyphens to your original command.

NG not beign very clear with that, use NPM to understand that instead :

```
npm run start -- --prod
```

Will run

```
ng serve --prod
```

Because in the `package.json` file, the default command for `start` is

```
"start": "ng serve",
```